# Error trying to access to Data Object definition in a project that have included a dependency to Gson library (solved)

Tags: object, gson, jbpm

I'm using the jBPM Server distribution, exactly the jBPM 7.74.1.Final server (single zip) distribution and I have install it in my local machine.
I have a project with different Data Objects to manage calls to differents externals API Rest. I have define all the needed Data Objects and as this interface used Json to send parameters and receive reponse, I decided to use an very common Json parsing library (Gson). I had to include this dependency in the project settings:
[Dependencies for the parsing library Gson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCOkp.png)

and I have modified the java code to parsing JSON in the created Data Objects. I can compile and execute the process and everything works fine.
The problem is that I don't be able to view the created Data Objects. When I try to access to a Data Object (into the Assets sheet) I get the next error:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError:tried to access class com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22 from class
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22$1

[Error trying to view an Data Object with GSON dependency included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Y6v.png)

Then, I can't view, modify, create or delete Data Objects.

What I am mainly confused is that when I delete the dependence to the library I can access to the diferent Data Objects created, modifying, deleting or creating. Obsviusly, if I compile the diagram I have errors related with the differents code lines when the library is invoked and used.

Is there any workaround I can give it a try?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a class loading issue; possibly you have Gson twice on your classpath at runtime and some of Gson's classes are loaded from one JAR whereas the others are loaded from the other JAR? Additionally, Gson version 2.3.1 is from 2014, could you please try the latest version? (but that will probably not solve the underlying issue that there are two Gson JARs on the classpath)

Comment: Hi, I have not GSON in my classpath, only in the project settings (Dependencies), but I have try your recomendation with the latest version, 2.10.1 and now everything works fine; I can view, modify and do everything with the defined Data Objects.
Thanks a lot.